# AES must have a fixed IV size of 16-bytes regardless key size

Tags: ios, objective-c, aes

Hello I am using [BBAES](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBAES) to encrypt and decrypt my code. But I am getting an error like this in this line.

```
encryptedData=[bb encryptedDataFromData:[bb dataFromString:_secret encoding:BBAESDataEncodingBase64] IV:[bb dataFromString:iv encoding:BBAESDataEncodingBase64] key:hashKeyData options:BBAESEncryptionOptionsIncludeIV];
```

And my error is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'AES must have a fixed IV size of 16-bytes regardless key size.'
```

This is how I create my `hashKeyData`

```
hashKeyData=[bb keyByHashingPassword:_key keySize:BBAESSaltDefaultLength];
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting your `iv` string into iv data by calling

```
[bb dataFromString:iv encoding:BBAESDataEncodingBase64]
```

This will give you more or less than 16 bytes, depending on `iv` which is why you are getting the exception.

The function that you should use use is `IVFromString:`.  This uses an MD5 hash to create an NSData instance which will be 16 bytes.

```
encryptedData=[bb encryptedDataFromData:[bb dataFromString:_secret encoding:BBAESDataEncodingBase64] IV:[bb IVString:iv] key:hashKeyData options:BBAESEncryptionOptionsIncludeIV];
```

Comment: Hello  Thanks for your reply,, But now im getting an error like this *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BBAES IVFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1366c6da0' why is that?